# Rmarkdown doc doesn't compile with python chunk

Tags: r, python-3.x, r-markdown, reticulate

I'm trying to use the `reticulate` package to run Python chunks in an .Rmd file. My problem is that the Python code will run in-line, but the document won't knit-- it hangs at 100% with no output and there are no error messages.

I assumed it was a PATH issue, but that's clearly fixed because the Python works. I am running R 3.5.1 64bit with Python 3.6.5 via Anaconda.

I'm able to knit docs that don't include Python. All libraries are updated. Here's a very simple example that doesn't run:

````
---
title: Test Reticulate Document
output: html_document 
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library("knitr")
library("reticulate")
```


```{python}
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print("Hello World!")
```
````

How can I get the document to compile?

Edit: I'm on Windows 10

Comment: Do you know the path to your Anaconda installation of Python 3.6.5?

Comment: @duckmayr it's at ```C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3```

Comment: I would try adding the line `use_python("C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/bin/python", required=TRUE)` in your R chunk under `library("reticulate")`

Comment: Just tried that. If I include the bin/python at the end I get a "does not exist" error. If I remove that, it runs up to 100% and then hangs again. No output. Same with ```use_condaenv()```.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem described here recently (2021 Aug) that python code chunk is not evaluated but hanging forever whenever I try to knit it.

I solved this issue by setting a default python interpreter on RStudio Global options. Weirdly, RStudio did not have a default python interpreter there. This was hard for me to notice because I did not encounter any problem running reticulate python on RStudio before (I set `RETICULATE_PYTHON` path on `.Renviron`).

Hope this may help others.